# Making sure Prototype.js code runs for AJAX content?

Tags: ajax, tabs, prototypejs

Is there a way to make sure some Prototype.js functions run any time there's a new element added to the page via AJAX? Normally, I'd just use jQuery's `live();` but we aren't using that on this site.

In this instance, I've made a tab interface but I know it's going to be called in a lightbox in a few instances. While it works when already on the page, if I load it in via an AJAX call it doesn't work (unsurprisingly).

What's the best way to go about fixing this issue? I did some searching but didn't find a good solution. Had I my preference you wouldn't need to do anything specific. The page would just find them automatically and do what needed to be done. Bonus points for a minimal hit in browser performance through unnecessary calls.

Example: http://designbyadmiral.com/experiments/tab_test.html

Comment: I think your best bet is to open jQuery and look at how .live() was implemented.

Comment: Have been, but I can't make heads or tails of how it works.

Comment: This may help you start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: I talked to the other (more experienced with the site) developers and it turns out we use Prototype.js for everything, including where we use AJAX. So I just wrapped my JS in a function and have it called any time an AJAX call completes.

Comment: Also, I eventually found this: http://axonflux.com/how-to-get-jquerys-live-behavior-in-prototype

Comment: Good score on that one. I started with Prototype when it first came out but moved to jQuery about four years ago.

Comment: FYI another way of getting the `live()` functionality is with [`Event.on`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) (or [`Element#on`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/on/) to use it directly)